# Installing VirtualBox 5.1 on CentOS 7.3

Tags: virtualbox, centos7

Has anyone been able to install VirtualBox 5.1 successfully on a CentOS 7.3 x64 box? Installing it via YUM succeeds, but calling "vagrant -v" shows the following:

```
This system is not currently set up to build kernel modules (system extensions).
Running the following commands should set the system up correctly:
  yum install kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
(The last command may fail if your system is not fully updated.)
  yum install kernel-devel
```

**kernel-devel** is installed already as part of dependencies. So it seems VirtualBox expects the 7.2 kernel modules. Has anyone been able to install VirtualBox 5.1 on kernel **3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, in case it might be useful for someone else.

(1) Visit https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/updates/7.2.1511/x86_64/Packages/kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64.html

(2) Download the RPM (kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64.rpm)

(3) Run `yum localinstall -y /path/to/kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64.rpm` to install "kernel-devel".

(4) Run `/sbin/vboxconfig` to further configure VirtualBox.

If you are using Ansible, you need something like the below before installing it via YUM (only if you have a system that does not have the correct kernel sources).

```
# Required kernel module
- name: Copy required kernel modules
  copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/{{ vbox_kernel_devel_rpm }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ vbox_kernel_devel_rpm }}"
- name: Install kernel-devel module
  shell: "yum localinstall -y /tmp/{{ vbox_kernel_devel_rpm }}"
  args:
    warn: false
- name: Delete uploaded RPM
  file: path="/tmp/{{ vbox_kernel_devel_rpm }}", state=absent
```

Answer (score 0):

I had machines where the kernel version was different so I found it easier to do this in scripts with:

```
curl -s ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-devel-$(uname -r).rpm -o kernel-devel-$(uname -r).rpm

sudo yum localinstall kernel-devel-$(uname -r).rpm
sudo yum install docker-engine VirtualBox-5.1 kernel-headers gcc
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

This could be customised further with CentOS version in the url.